# Updating S3 credentials via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am writing automation to update softlayer's S3 account keys. I know I can do it via UI. Is there any option to do it via api (python / java/ rest/ cli)?

I could not see anything in `slcli` nor can I see any rest endpoint here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/softlayerapi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not possible to update the credentials or ACCESS KEYS of a S3 by control portal and api, you can only create and delete the credentials (ACCESS KEYS).

The Object Storage S3 has a limit of 2 credentials by default. If you already have 2 credentials created, you must delete one of them in order to create another.

To know the limit of your credentials for your S3, use the following rest call:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/[networkStorageAccountId]/getCredentialLimit
```

Reference:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/getCredentialLimit/

To retrieve the credentials, use the below rest call:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/[networkStorageAccountId]/getCredentials
```

Reference:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/getCredentials/

To create a credential use this rest call:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/[networkStorageAccountId]/credentialCreate
```

Reference:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/credentialCreate/

To delete a credential:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/[networkStorageAccountId]/credentialDelete
```

Body: Json

```
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
        "id": 11111
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace the 11111 data with your credentialId.

Reference:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/credentialDelete/

Comment: Thanks yes I meant deleting and creating. I assume there is no slcli option for this.

Comment: Currently the slcli does not support create and delete s3 credentials. I already opened an issue for this, you can see it in the following link: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/1127.